# List of object array from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Resorces>
<Resource id="3" name="loreum ipsum" downloadcount="5"></Resource>
<Resource id="2" name="loreum ipsum" downloadcount="9"></Resource>
</Resorces>
```

I have a class

```
public class Report
{
    public int ResourceId {get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int DownloadCount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert that xml into list of Report objects

I tried the below code

```
var resourceList = doc.Descendants("Resorces")
                                    .First()
                                    .Elements("Resource")
                                    .ToList();
```

I get values like this,

[image]

How can I get it as list of objects?

Comment: If that's something you can still change: Theplural of **resource** is **resources**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are missing is the part where you convert the Xml objects into your defined object of `Report`. This is how you can do it:

```
var resourceList = doc.Descendants("Resorces")
                       .First()
                       .Elements("Resource")
                       .Select(element => new Report()
                                  {
                                    ResourceId = (int)element.Attribute("id"),
                                    ResourceName = (string)element.Attribute("name"),
                                    DownloadCount = (int)element.Attribute("downloadcount")
                                  })
                       .ToList();
```

*I kept here the previous linq methods you called to keep it close to the original but as others said you can just get the `Elements("Resource")` from the doc root*

Answer (score 2):

```
 XmlDocument newdoc = new XmlDocument();
newdoc.InnerXml = " <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Resorces>
<Resource id="3" name="loreum ipsum" downloadcount="5"></Resource>
<Resource id="2" name="loreum ipsum" downloadcount="9"></Resource>
</Resorces>";
List<string> list = new List <string>();
var selectnode = "Resorces/Resource";
var nodes = newdoc.SelectNodes(selectnode);
foreach (XmlNode nod in nodes)
{
    string id = nod["id"].InnerText;
    string name    = nod["name"].InnerText;
    string downloadcount = nod["downloadcount"].InnerText;       
    list.Add(id);
    list.Add(name);
    list.Add(downloadcount);
}
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Elements` method to get elements for a given element name.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    var result = doc.Root
       .Elements("Resource")
       .Select(x=> new Report()
                {
                    ResourceId = int.Parse( x.Attribute("id").Value),
                    ResourceName = (string)x.Attribute("name").Value,
                    DownloadCount = int.Parse( x.Attribute("downloadcount").Value)

                })
        .ToList();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/guOd3F)

Answer (score 1):

You can get by this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);

List<Report> resourceList = doc.Descendants("Resorces")
                                    .First()
                                    .Elements("Resource")
                                    .Select(report => new Report()
                                                          {
                                        ResourceId = (int)report.Attribute("id"),
                                        ResourceName = (string)report.Attribute("name"),
                                        DownloadCount = (int)report.Attribute("downloadcount")
                                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's identical to @GiladGreen's answer

Comment: everyone's answer almost identical here